# Why do I loss 1 MB when I delete a partition and try recreate it with Windows Disk Management?

Tags: windows, partitioning

If I create the following partitions (all simple volume) on a drive:

(a) 102400 MB | (b) 102400 MB | (c) The Rest Space

If I delete either (a) or (b) then try to create a simple volume in the unallocated space left, the maximum disk space shows "102399" instead of "102400".

If I delete both (a) and (b) then try to create a simple volume, the maximum space shows "204799" instead of "204800".

This behavior can be tested with a vhd, and it doesn't matter if the disk is MBR/GPT and/or Simple/Dynamic.

**Why can't I recreate a volume of same size in place where I just deleted one?**

Surely 1 MB isn't much considering the capacity of today's drives, but I prefer to add 1 MB when creating a partition to have it shown in Windows as 100 GB (102401 MB) instead of 99.99 GB and losing that 1 MB would result in the annoying 0.99 problem.

---

So someone marked this question as a duplicate, which I did read before posting this question and didn't really consider it as a duplicate.

1. I'm not doing any resizing.
2. The answers in that almost 4-years-old-question doesn't answer mine - why is this happening? Let's assume if there're some extra spaces need for a partition, it must be requried for the original partition (which I deleted) as well, why would it suddenly require more? It's not like I'm trying to create multiple partitions.

Comment: FWIW, you're asking people to answer a why question they can not possibly answer as none of us actually wrote diskpart or disk management. All we can, just like you, is observe what happens. For the rest, you don't tell where you got the numbers from, where do you see this, and give exact steps so if someone wanted, he could try recrate the issue.

Comment: I don't recall it happens if there's no partition that follows the space you are going to recreate/resize partition with, but I'll have to test to be sure. Other than that, it's just basically Microsoft prefers to leave a gap. There're literally tons of silly things like this in Windows.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen I've clearly stated in the title that I'm using Windows Disk Manager and have described what I've done step by step, what exactly are you referring to that "I'm not telling where I got the numbers from"? Isn't the entire point of an online community to ask if someone else understands something you don't? I'm not skilled to track down the cause doesn't mean someone doesn't have this knowledge, "others can not possibly answer it" seems a little arrogant, don't you agree?

Comment: @TomYan Yes, it doesn't happen if there's no partition follows, which is why I was able to create this layout in the beginning with no problem. I should have write this as an answer but since this question is closed I'll write it here: DiskPart doesn't have this limitation, it must be some kind of undocumented behavior of the Windows Disk Manager.

Comment: @RadarNyan, no I don't agree.